# httppost data used for database queries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, mysql-connector

I have two fields of string data from an asp MVC entity framework view. Through model binding, I now have this data back in the httppost action function. I would now like to use this data to pass to a query in the mysql database.

The query will only be a read only query to fetch some records.  Any pointers on how this can be achieved please? The application is a MVC ASP Core EntityFramework type of project.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(Login loginData)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // check the parameters passed against what's in the db and if they match, do things. Else, report login/password error


        } else
        {
            // show error
        }
        return View();

    }
```

Am a newbie to ASP MVC/ entity framework. Would appreciate any links to examples.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link of [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/),and here is a link of [EF Core with MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

EF Core example(find a user by id):

```
var User=_context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.id == loginData.id);
```